# Zipping .xlsx/.xls file in java : problem in creating workbook.create()

Tags: excel, zip, xlsx, xls

I am trying to convert.xls/.xlsx file to a zipped file. The code I am using is:

Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(File);
wb.write(zipOutputStream);

It throws an error in workbook creation:

Cannot remove block[11047]; index out of range[0-9946]